# What would be the best way to generate website from db

Tags: c#, asp.net, markdown

We have a lot of red tape to handle before any changes to anything can be made on our servers. Hence I'm looking for ideas and/or suggestions for the below situation.

Must generate html from db (MSSql Server) for a static website hosted on IIS 6/7.
No (external) changes should be necessary on the server side except the ones the application/website makes itself.

I tried markdown and it generates everything nicely but I could not find a way to make the above idea applicable with it. I am willing to put all html code in the db for each individual page but it sounds awkward. Should I go with something ASP.NET'ish or a Windows Service or a standalone app to run at a schedule.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Does it mean that also the markup/presentation layer would be stored in DB? Or only data? Sounds a bit confusing for me.

Comment: Its a simple informational site with static content. Like a help site. The contents change little but often as every week. I presumed we can keep everything in the db but data sounds more sensible.

Comment: Usually only data is stored in db. Separation of data and presentation is a basic principle that you should follow. Asp .net is your best option. You can also use some open source cms.

Comment: I understand. I thought maybe there was a magical way to go:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Dynamic Data might be your technology of choice.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee845452%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

However, my advice is that you'll never be able to solve your problems by something like the above. You need to work out how to do releases more often - maybe start with a CI server and start scripting your releases if you haven't already.